# Error error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to Import Google Map sdk in my Project. When I write the code every thing is okay except this error(error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype).

I search a lot but nothing is enough to get rid of this error.

This is my Main Activity named as (GoogleMap.java)

```
 public class GoogleMap extends AppCompatActivity {
//map data
private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";
private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map);

    //map data
    if (isServicesOK()) {
        init();
    }
}
//MAP DATA
public void init() {
    Button btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
    btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(GoogleMap.this, MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public boolean isServicesOK() {
    Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: checking google services version");
    int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(GoogleMap.this);
    if (available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Play Services is Working");
        return true;
    } else if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)) {
        //an error occured but we can resolve it
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: an error occured but we can fix it");
        Dialog dialog =  GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(GoogleMap.this, available, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "you can,t make map request",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return false;
}
 }
```

Here is my Second Activity named as (MapActivity.java)

```
 public abstract class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
    mMap = googleMap;
}

private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

//vars
private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    getLocationPermission();
}

private void initMap(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
}

private void getLocationPermission(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                permissions,
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
    mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

    switch(requestCode){
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
            if(grantResults.length > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                    if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                //initialize our map
                initMap();
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

As I think the Problem is Specifically in this Block of code.(The redline is shown under the word @override)

```
  @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
    mMap = googleMap;
}
```

Here is my build failed Stack Trace:

```
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
```

Here is java compiler failed stack trace:

```
 error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

How I can get rid of this error?

Comment: name your Activity something different from `GoogleMap`, as there already exists class `GoogleMap`. That's why the compiler is conused about which `GoogleMap` you want to use

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I renamed it according to your suggestion but it doesn,t work.

Comment: what you renamed it to, and what is the problem now?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I renamed GoogleMap to GoogleMapLocation but error is still same here.

Comment: does the method still look like `public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {`? Or it hanged too?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko now again i renamed GoogleMapLocation to GoogleMapLocat but again same error is showing.

Comment: please check the prev. comment

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko this method is also changed because I (select all) option before . now the method looks like.      public void onMapReady(GoogleMapLocat googleMapLocat)

Comment: that's exactly what I am talking about. change this method to `public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {`

Comment: Yeah! You are right 100% but now error is switched to. this line( mMap = googleMap;) and also runtime exception occur

Comment: change the type of `mMap`

Comment: now the error is (Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 87606 > 65536))

Comment: It can be fixed using search. You have to always use search first. It would take me 10 min to type, or 20 seconds for you to search